# Use LINQ to move item to top of list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Is there a way to move an item of say id=10 as the first item in a list using LINQ?

```
Item A - id =5
Item B - id = 10
Item C - id =12
Item D - id =1
```

In this case how can I elegantly move Item C to the top of my `List<T>` collection?

This is the best I have right now:

```
var allCountries = repository.GetCountries();
var topitem = allCountries.Single(x => x.id == 592);  
var finalList = new List<Country>();
finalList.Add(topitem);
finalList = finalList.Concat(allCountries.Where(x=> x.id != 592)).ToList();
```

Comment: Would you want to swap the item with the top item or rotate the items by pushing all items until the found item down.

Comment: didn;t **finalList .insert(0,"neww stuff");** work

Answer (score 57, accepted):

LINQ is strong in querying collections, creating projections over existing queries or generating new queries based on existing collections.  It is not meant as a tool to re-order existing collections inline.  For that type of operation it's best to use the type at hande.

Assuming you have a type with a similar definition as below

```
class Item {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  ..
}
```

Then try the following

```
List<Item> list = GetTheList();
var index = list.FindIndex(x => x.Id == 12);
var item = list[index];
list[index] = list[0];
list[0] = item;
```

Comment: +1 Works well for the swap scenario, I gotta feelin' that a rotate is actually required tho'

Comment: This is more or less what i did any way, but thanks for the explanation as to why there is seemingly not a better way :)

Comment: For error handling, note that you should check the `FindIndex` result value, it is -1 if the item isn't found in the list.

Comment: Isn't this just swapping the first element with the target element index rather than move the target element to the top and move everything else down?

Answer (score 150):

What do you want to order by, other than the known top item? If you don't care, you can do this:

```
var query = allCountries.OrderBy(x => x.id != 592).ToList();
```

Basically, "false" comes before "true"...

Admittedly I don't know what this does in LINQ to SQL etc. You may need to stop it from doing the ordering in the database:

```
var query = allCountries.AsEnumerable()
                        .OrderBy(x => x.id != 592)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: its doesn't work as expected for LINQ to SQL. I just tested it.

Comment: +1 Thanks Jon. I wanted to order by name but keep the item with id=0 on top so I did this: allCountries.OrderBy(x => x.id == 0 ? "00000" : x.Name).ToList(); performance isn't an issue because the list is small.

Comment: For someone reviewing the code later it might not be obvious that boolean values are ordered "false, true". I would recommend the more verbose solutions over this.

Comment: Beautiful! I wanted a `Name` in a small list on the top or Index 0,in LINQ to  Entities, and it did the trick Thanks +1.  `db.Systms.Where(s => s.IsActive == true).OrderBy(x => x.SystemName != "Portal Administration").ToList();`

Answer (score 48):

Linq generallyworks on Enumerables, so it doesn't now that the underlying type is a collection. So for moving the item on top of the list I would suggest using something like (if you need to preserve the order)

```
var idx = myList.FindIndex(x => x.id == 592);
var item = myList[idx];
myList.RemoveAt(idx);
myList.Insert(0, item);
```

If your function returns only an IEnumerable, you can use the `ToList()` method to convert it to a List first

If you don't preserve the order you can simply swap the values at position 0 and position idx

Comment: This is perfect for the rotate down scenario instead of just swapping the values.

Answer (score 48):

```
var allCountries = repository.GetCountries();
allCountries.OrderByDescending(o => o.id == 12).ThenBy(o => o.id)
```

This will insert the object with id=12 at the top of the list and rotate the rest down, preserving the order.

Comment: I love this thought process, but D has an ID of 1, so wouldn't this order it as C, D, A, B?

Comment: @PhatWrat Sure, so if you wanted to avoid that you would say .ThenBy(o => o.name) or something similar

Comment: Should be the top answer! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Here is an extension method you might want to use. It moves the element(s) that match the given predicate to the top, preserving order.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MoveToTop(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, bool> func) {
    return list.Where(func)
               .Concat(list.Where(item => !func(item)));
}
```

In terms of complexity, I think it would make two passes on the collection, making it O(n), like the Insert/Remove version, but better than Jon Skeet's OrderBy suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I know this a old question but I did it like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new int[] { 5, 10, 12, 1 };

        var ordered = numbers.OrderBy(num => num != 10 ? num : -1);

        foreach (var num in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("number is {0}", num);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

this prints:

number is 10 
number is 1
number is 5
number is 12

Answer (score 3):

You can "group by" in two groups with Boolean key, and then sort them

```
var finalList= allCountries
                .GroupBy(x => x.id != 592)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x=> x.id ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Even easier if you have the object:

```
listOfObjects.Remove(object);
listOfObjects.Insert(0, object);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ServeFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    Predicate<T> p)
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    foreach (var s in source)
    {
        if (p(s))
            yield return s;
        else
            list.Add(s);
    }

    foreach (var s in list)
        yield return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its interesting the number of approaches you find when trying to solve a problem.

```
var service = AutogateProcessorService.GetInstance();
var allConfigs = service.GetAll();
allConfigs = allConfigs.OrderBy(c => c.ThreadDescription).ToList();
var systemQueue = allConfigs.First(c => c.AcquirerId == 0);
allConfigs.Remove(systemQueue);
allConfigs.Insert(0, systemQueue);
```

Answer (score 1):

To also check if the item was found without Exception, something like:

```
var allCountries = repository.GetCountries();
var lookup = allCountries.ToLookup(x => x.id == 592);  
var finalList = lookup[true].Concat(lookup[false]).ToList();
if ( lookup[true].Count() != 1 ) YouAreInTrouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a static extension method to do this. Note this doesn't preserve the order, it simply swaps the item out. If you needed to preserve the order you should do a rotate not a simple swap.

```
/// <summary>
/// Moves the item to the front of the list if it exists, if it does not it returns false
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="collection"></param>
/// <param name="predicate"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool MoveToFrontOfListWhere<T>(this List<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (collection == null || collection.Count <= 0) return false;

    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
    {
        T element = collection.ElementAt(i);
        if (!predicate(element)) continue;
        index = i;
        break;
    }

    if (index == -1) return false;

    T item = collection[index];
    collection[index] = collection[0];
    collection[0] = item;
    return true;
}
```