# I have a list of countries. I'd like to sort it alphabetically, except for two countries which I'd like to put first

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of countries. I'd like to sort it alphabetically, except for two countries which I'd like to put first. Is there a simple way to modify

```
from country in Countries
orderby country.Name
select country
```

to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just sort it then move those two to be first?

Comment: That's an option, but it's not very elegant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var specialCountries = new[] { "America", "England" };

from country in Countries
orderby specialCountries.Contains(country.Name) descending, country.Name
select country
```

If this isn't LINQ-to-Objects, you might need to write it slightly differently for it to work, e.g. this might work

```
from country in Countries
orderby (country.Name == "America" || country.Name == "England") descending, country.Name
select country
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this trick:

```
var ordered = Countries.OrderByDescending(c => ConditionHere)
                       .ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

for example:

```
var priorCountries = new[]{ "Italy", "France" };
var ordered = Countries.OrderByDescending(c => priorCountries.Contains(c.Name))
                       .ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **original list**, which contains every country.

```
var originalList = new List<string> { "B", "A", "E", "D", "C", "F" };
```

An **exclusionary list**, where you provide the order of items you'd like at the front.

```
var items = new List<string> { "E", "F" };
```

Your results.

```
items.AddRange(originalList.Except(items)
                           .OrderBy(q => q));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from country in countries
orderby (country.Name = "USA" ? 0 : 1), country.Name
select country
```

Of course, you'll need to change the criteria, but the point is that you can perform some evaluation in the orderby clause.