# Reorder a List of string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of string List which contains all state names.
I need to move few states(Ex New York, California etc) to appear at the top of the list.
How can I do this using LINQ?
FYI: the list is alreday sorted in alphabetical order.

Its just a simple List and few important states needs to be at the top. No criteria.

Comment: And this is all server-side? Why the 'jquery' tag? Please edit your question and add your existing code.

Comment: what's the criteria for being on the top of the list? or are there just a few that should be on top by their names?

Comment: Why "using LINQ", how are the "few states" provided, etc.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668451/use-linq-to-move-item-to-top-of-list

Comment: Its just a simple List<String> and few important states needs to be at the top. No criteria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a proof of concept using letters instead of states.

```
var all = new List<string>() {"a","b","c","d","e"};
var top = new List<string>() {"c","d"};

var finalList = top.Concat(all.Except(top));
```

The idea is that you have your full list of states (`all`) and a list of the ones you want at the top ('top'). You then take the ones at the top and concatenate the list of the remaining ones that you create using the `Except` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> importantStates = {...};//It's up to you
var list = states.OrderBy(x=>!importantStates.Contains(x));
```