# linq query to sort and then bring a particular group of records to top

Tags: linq

i am trying a linq query to sort a group of elements and then bring a elements that satisfy particular condition to top.

for eg, if i have list of elements like below:

```
ID   Names
1    Angie
2    Bret
3    Salva
4    cunnighma
5    maria
6    Galvin
7    Newton 
8    Desmond
```

and if i pass condition as Name=Galvin then the resultset should be sorted first and then bring the value inn condition to top.The resultset would like below

```
   ID    Names
    6    Galvin
    1    Angie
    2    Bret
    4    cunnighma
    8    Desmond
    5    maria
    7    Newton 
    3    Salva
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use LINQ to move item to top of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668451/use-linq-to-move-item-to-top-of-list)

Comment: Thanx this is what i am expecting!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create an extension method that can be used in your linq expression. The following solution does just that. I've made it work for the case of multiple matches as well.

The example code below will have the following output:

```
6:Galvin
1:Angie
2:Bret
4:cunnighma
8:Desmond
5:maria
7:Newton
3:Salva
```

Here's the code:

```
void Main()
{
    // Setup the example data
    var names = new List<Record>
    {
        new Record { Id = 1, Name = "Angie" },
        new Record { Id = 2, Name = "Bret" },
        new Record { Id = 3, Name = "Salva" },
        new Record { Id = 4, Name = "cunnighma" },
        new Record { Id = 5, Name = "maria" },
        new Record { Id = 6, Name = "Galvin" },
        new Record { Id = 7, Name = "Newton" },
        new Record { Id = 8, Name = "Desmond" }
    };
    
    // Sort the list and move the matches to the top
    var result = names
       .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
       .MoveToTop(x => x.Name.Contains("alvin"));

    // Display the results to the console
    result
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Id}:{x.Name}"));
}


public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MoveToTop<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,  Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var matches = list.Where(predicate);            
        return matches.Concat(list.Except(matches));
    }
}
```