# Move list elements meeting condition to the top of the list

Tags: c#

I want to move specific number to the top of this list.

```
int numberToBeMovedOnTop = 4;
List<int> lst = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 7, 9, 4, 2, 1};
List<int> lstOdd = lst.FindAll(l => l == numberToBeMovedOnTop);
lstOdd.AddRange(lst.FindAll(l => l != numberToBeMovedOnTop));
```

Where `numberToBeMovedOnTop` is a variable.

This gives me the desired result but is a better solution for this? I can iterate the list once and swap first occurence of `numberToBeMovedOnTop` with first element, second occurence with `numberToBeMovedOnTop` with second element and so on. But can this be done with some built-in C# function without iterating the list twice?

Comment: Check this question out, contains a load of different methods for doing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668451/use-linq-to-move-item-to-top-of-list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
List<int> lstOdd = lst.OrderByDescending(i => i == numberToBeMovedOnTop).ToList();
```

Why `OrderByDescending`? Because the comparison returns a `bool` and `true` is higher than `false`. You could also use:

```
List<int> lstOdd = lst.OrderBy(i => i == numberToBeMovedOnTop ? 0 : 1).ToList();
```

Note that this works because [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) and `OrderByDescending` are performing a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts). That means that the original order remains for all equal items.

---

For what it's worth, here is an extension method that works with any type and predicate and is a little bit more efficient:

```
public static List<T> PrependAll<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var returnList = new List<T>();
    var listNonMatch = new List<T>();
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
            returnList.Add(item);
        else
            listNonMatch.Add(item);
    }
    returnList.AddRange(listNonMatch);
    return returnList;
}
```

Usage: `List<int> lstOdd = lst.PrependAll(i => i == numberToBeMovedOnTop);`

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using linq, it might be just as efficient/understandable to do this without linq

```
var listToAdd = new List<int>();
var listOdd = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
{
    if(lst[i] == numberToBeMovedOnTop)
    {
        listToAdd.Add(numberToBeMovedOnTop);
    }
    else
    {
        listOdd.Add(lst[i]);
    }

}
listOdd.AddRange(listToAdd);
```

Keep track of those that you've removed, then add them on afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Group by the predicate, then union?

```
        var nums = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        var grp = nums.GroupBy(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList();
        var changed = grp[0].Union(grp[1]).ToList();
```

Comment: Your predicate is different, but you get the idea