# Linq Select OrderBy ThenBy Kendo Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, kendo-ui

My application is MVC5.  I am populating Countries Kendo Dropdownlist, trying to place Canada and United States at the top of the list using:

```
     public JsonResult GetCountries()
            {
                return Json(db.Country.OrderBy(x => x.TwoCharCountryCode == "CA")
                .ThenBy(x => x.TwoCharCountryCode == "US").ThenBy(x => x.CountryName)
             .Select(c => new { CountryId = c.CountryId, CountryName = c.CountryName }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }



              @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                  .Name("Country")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;", id="Country", value = ViewBag.CountryId })
                 .OptionLabel("Select country...")
                  .DataTextField("CountryName")
                  .DataValueField("CountryId")
                  .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("GetCountries", "Home");
                      }).ServerFiltering(true);
                  })
                  .Events(e => {e.Select("onSelect");
                  }))
```

I get Canada and the USA at the bottom!
[image]

Can I use two ThenBy?  or what am I  doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just force LINQ translator to create correct query:

```cs
var query = db.Country
   .OrderBy(x => x.TwoCharCountryCode == "CA" 
      ? 0 
      : x.TwoCharCountryCode == "US"
      ? 1 : 2)
   .ThenBy(x => x.CountryName)
   .Select(c => new { CountryId = c.CountryId, CountryName = c.CountryName });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `.OrderBy` or `ThenBy` a boolean value, `False`, which means 0, will always come before `True`, which means 1.

If you have to put Canada and USA on top of the list, and order the rest, I would just get those two out of the list first, re-order the rest of the list, and put everything back together:

```cs
public JsonResult GetCountries()
{
    var canadaOrUsa = db.Country
        .Where(x => x.TwoCharCountryCode == "CA" ||
                    x.TwoCharCountryCode == "US")
        .OrderBy(x => x.CountryName);

    var theRest = db.Country
        .Where(x => x.TwoCharCountryCode != "CA" &&
                    x.TwoCharCountryCode != "US")
        .OrderBy(x => x.CountryName);

    return Json(
        canadaOrUsa.Concat(theRest)
            .Select(x => new {
                CountryId = x.CountryId, 
                CountryName = x.CountryName
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you don't want to enumerate the list twice, I guess you can `.ToList()` from your `db.Country`, find Canada and USA, and take them out of the list, order the left-over, and then put them back to the beginning of the list.

@configurator wrote an extension method about moving items to the top of the list here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668662/2410655

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> MoveToTop(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, bool> func) {
    return list.Where(func)
               .Concat(list.Where(item => !func(item)));
}
```

You can use that to reduce lines of code you need to write:

```cs
public JsonResult GetCountries()
{
    var result = db.Country
        .OrderBy(x => x.CountryName)
        .MoveToTop(x => x.TwoCharCountryCode == "CA" ||
                    x.TwoCharCountryCode == "US");

    return Json(
        result
            .Select(x => new {
                CountryId = x.CountryId, 
                CountryName = x.CountryName
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```